# how to solve Pandas read json Type error?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I now having the problem when read JSON using pandas.read_json. For instance, the JSON type have been got from redis like this

```
b'{"enable":false,"symbol":"abcdef","skew_rate":1,"skew_judge":0.05,"skew_range":0.0001,"skew_end_time":4,"skew_start_time":6}'
```

I'm using this line of code to change it to series

```
pd.read_json(r.get('key_{}'.format(symbol)),typ='series')
```

But it return this Type Error

```
TypeError: <class 'bool'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Meanwhile I do not convert any key in the json data type to datetime. Why does it give me this error? How to fix this problem? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have keys that end with `_time` and default value for `convert_dates` is `True` it try to convert these to date. You can pass `convert_dates=False` to avoid it

```
foo = b'{"enable":false,"symbol":"abcdef","skew_rate":1,"skew_judge":0.05,"skew_range":0.0001,"skew_end_time":4,"skew_start_time":6}'

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(foo, typ='series', convert_dates=False)
print(df.head())
```

output

```
enable         False
symbol        abcdef
skew_rate          1
skew_judge      0.05
skew_range    0.0001
dtype: object
```